# How to check the database value in string in php

Tags: php, string

Here is the my code..

```
    <?php
$SupportingMaterialTaskSql = "select task_name,section_name,ref_student_id from scores where ref_student_id = '".$studentid."' and section_name = 'sm1' GROUP BY task_name ORDER BY cast( SUBSTRING( task_name, 5, 2 ) AS unsigned ) ASC";

            $SupportingMaterialTaskResults = $obj->selectQuery($SupportingMaterialTaskSql);

            if($SupportingMaterialTaskResults > 0)
            {
                foreach($SupportingMaterialTaskResults as $Key => $SupportingMaterialTaskRow)
                {
                    $Task = $SupportingMaterialTaskRow['task_name'];

                    $str = "Task";
                    $TaskName = str_replace($str, "Task ", $Task);
?>
                <tr>
                  <td width="30%"  class="f13_blue cellbg"><?php echo $TaskName; ?></td>
                </tr> 
                <?php 
                } 

            } 
            ?>
```

Here is the Out put above this code..

```
Task2 Task3 Task5 Task6 Task7 Task8 Task9 Task10
```

So just i want to result like this.. if database have value like Task1 then print Task1 otherwise Print Task1 "N/A".

So how can i solve that?

Comment: Are the Task values, table columns?

Comment: task_name  section_name  ref_student_id
 Task10    sm1    1
 Task2    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task4    sm1    1
 Task4    sm1    1
 Task5    sm1    1
 Task6    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task8    sm1    1
 Task9    sm1    1

Comment: Yes this is the "task_name" field value.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/if_structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following could work:

```
<?php

function check_not_null($var){
  if(trim($var) == ""){
    $var = "N/A";
  }
  return($var);
}


// some query info here...


while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $task1 = check_not_null($fetch['task1']);
  $task2 = check_not_null($fetch['task2']);
  $task3 = check_not_null($fetch['task3']);
  // now echo or use the vars.. each loop they will be rechecked..
}

?>
```